# ios UITableView: How do I show the right list of data on the specific Header Section?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5

So I have a acouple of sections on one of my views eg:

```
1. My Events
2. My Matches
3. All Events
```

Now I want to show a couple of rows (with a limit) on each section and then add another cell that will point to the main view.

Since the data will be coming from an API I still need to group my data to three sections which is easy enough as I have 3 arrays on that implementation eg:

```
@implementation MainOptionsController{
 NSArray *mainHeaders;
 NSArray *myEvents;
 NSArray *myMatches;
 NSArray *allEvents;
}

-(void)ViewDidLoad{
  [super ViewDidLoad];
  myEvents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"My Event 1", @"My Event 2", @"View More" nil];
  myMatches =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"My match 1", @"My match 2", @"View More" nil]; 
  allEvents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Event 1", @"Event 2", @"View More" nil];
}
```

I already displayed the Headers for each section but my problem is how do I display the array on their respective sections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following method in your tableView delegate class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

This method is called from the tableView foreach cell it displays.

Comment: sorry im kinda new to xcode. was wondering do I have to create a delegate class for every controller? Or can't you put that process on the controller where it resides?

Comment: Of course you can assign any class instance to the delegate property but ensure that class conforms the delegate's protocol.